# Validate Email In CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, email, spam

I have a website in CodeIgniter 3. I have a login and register form.
In Register form, I am using CodeIgniter validation rules for validating user inputs. Other are fine, I just want to talk about the `email validation rule`. Here is how I am doing this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|max_length[60]|valid_email|xss_clean|unique[user.email]');
```

And in HTML I have used the `Input type` attribute `email`. This attribute forces normal users to enter valid email addresses that's fine. But when I remove this `email` attribute, I am able to enter this as an email,

```
"<!sadasdd_?"@gmail.com
```

How is this a valid email? How do you validate email? and how can I prevent such spam inputs?

Comment: Why you tried to remove the HTML `email` attribute?
The <input type="email"> defines a field for an e-mail address.

With the `email` attribute, the input value is automatically validated to ensure it is a properly formatted e-mail address.

Comment: @MahmudHasanJion I did that to check the validation because I saw few entries in the database like those, so I tried, validation working or not, and I was able to register an account with an invalid email.

Comment: That is a valid email.  When you have double quotes in the first part, you can put almost any garbage in there.